# PL/SQL if statement error

Tags: plsql

Here is what I have in my stored procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_USER (IN IN_USER_NAME VARCHAR(256))
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN
    -- Declare cursor
    DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR WITH RETURN for

        IF (IN_USER_NAME IS NULL) THEN
            SELECT BLUEMSP.USERS.USER_ID FROM BLUEMSP.USERS;
        END IF;

    -- Cursor left open for client application
    OPEN cursor1;
END P1
```

I am getting an error on the If statement line that says

```
Multiple markers at this line
"." was expected instead of "(".
- "JOIN" was expected instead of "THEN".
- "IF (IN_USER_NAME IS NULL) THEN
        SELECT BLUEMSP.USERS.USER_ID FROM BLUEMSP." appears to be misplaced.
- "(" was expected after "IS".
```

Why is this not working?

Thanks

Comment: The syntax is not Oracle PL/SQL. Are you trying to run Microsoft T-SQL in Oracle ?

Comment: Its a DB2 sysntax and its not same as oracle PLSQL.

Comment: The PL/SQL compiler is happiest when you submit code written in the [PL/SQL language](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/toc.htm), not whatever this is.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use an `IF` statement in a cursor declaration, as `IF` is PL/SQL, and a cursor declaration must be pure SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_USER (IN_USER_NAME IN  VARCHAR2)
IS
xxx BLUEMSP.USERS.USER_ID%TYPE; 
CURSOR cursor1 IS SELECT BLUEMSP.USERS.USER_ID FROM BLUEMSP.USERS;
BEGIN
IF (IN_USER_NAME IS NULL) THEN               
   OPEN cursor1;
   FETCH cursor1 INTO xxx;
   ...
END IF
CLOSE cursor1;
END
```